# Binary classification without training data

Tags: machine-learning, classification

My goal is to classify students of an online course into two groups: "cheaters" and "non-cheaters". I have some features which can be useful (grade, number of videos watched, some actions with videos, and so on), but I haven't got training data.

How can I solve this problem? I will be grateful for some ideas or tips.

Comment: This seems more like a question in education or psychology than a question in statistics.  Someone who has minimal interaction with videos may have studied some of the material before and be taking the course to put everything in context. You can never be sure whether the people doing the work and typing answers are the same as the ones registered for the course. These days, it's hard enough to detect cheating on an exam in a real physical classroom. A major difficulty is it's too easy to hide a cell phone connection to someone who knows the material. Or to detect unauthorized web browsing.

Comment: Of course, you are right and I agree with you. But for my task at university I should come up with something suggesting that if student has minimal interaction with videos, solves all problems from the first attempt and so on he can be a cheater. It is just a educational task, not serious article.

Comment: If 'boss' has decided it's important to meas'degree of engagement with videos', then you should decide what metric you will use: Total length of time? Nr of sign-ons? Attempts to answer online Qs? Or maybe some fabricated 'index' that takes several of these into account. Then maybe see how your metric correlates with Final Exam  grade. // All of this seems OK to me as long as you claim only to be measuring engagement, not degree of cheating. If there are people who believe there is a connection btw non-eng. and cheating, let them. // Maybe post your Q on our Academia site.

Answer (score 1):

Tim makes an excellent point regarding ethics in his answer.  There is indeed a serious ethics issue in this kind of analysis, and you have to make sure that you are careful to make inferences with a proper statistical basis.  Moreover, you need to be careful not to make assertions that can't be backed up statistically, and ensure that any inferences you describe are described with the proper explanation of uncertainty.

Nevertheless, one thing that Tim did not mention, that I think it is worth noting, is that statistical models generally involve an unknown *true state* for a latent variable, and an *estimated state* of this variable.  The whole point of this binary classification problem is that there may indeed be students who are cheaters, and you are trying to make a prediction about this.  Obviously your inferences are not going to be perfect, so if you identify a student as a "cheater", you should be careful you frame your results with an appropriate qualifier --- e.g., you could describe the positive result as an inference subject to a quantifiable degree of uncertainty.  If you are careful about this then it may be reasonable for you to proceed with this kind of analysis, but again, it is important that inferences are described with the proper language for your uncertainty.

Now, if you do not have training data, and do not have any data with *known* cheating, with which to train your analysis, then any attempt to identify cheating in the test data will be subject to extremely large amounts of uncertainty.  Moreover, your inferences may hinge on demographic variables, in which case they will be discriminatory on those variables in ways that may not be justifiable with such poor data.  You will need to be careful not to make defamatory accusations, or make statements of inferences that are not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this question misses the [ethics](/questions/tagged/ethics) tag. No matter what data you have, or do not have, building an algorithm that labels someone as an exam cheater sounds highly unethical. What would be the follow-up of such classification? Repeating the course? Being expelled from the course? Say that your algorithm would have 0.1% false positives rate, then you would be falsely accusing 1 in 1000 people of cheating? Taking ethics aside, if based on the results predicted by this algorithm you acted on it's result as if the person was cheater, and say expelled them from the course, you would likely be sued.

Even worse, you say that you don't have training data. Since you mention some features, I guess that you mean that you don't know who was cheating and who wasn't. This means that you have no data nor to train, nor to validate the results. Yes, you could try using some kind of anomaly detection algorithm, but then you have no guarantee whatsoever that the discovered anomaly is in fact cheating. What if someone has strange patterns in watching the videos because of having low bandwidth internet connection? What if someone doesn't watch the videos because of being blind? I guess that there is an infinite number of reasons why someone would not fit the pattern that is popular among majority of the other people. During dark ages there were witch hunts for the red haired people, because such anomalous hair color was a likely indicator of witchcraft, as we all know.